# My pendrive is not showing

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

I an making my pen drive bootable but I suddenly eject it.
Till now it is not anymore normally showing.
However it is visible in disk management.
With some help I make it visible to the GPT, GUID(Globally Unique Identifier) Partition Table, but still it is not showing in windows.

How to make it again visible from windows?

Comment: Welcome on SU Ayush. Try always to specify under which operating system are you working (and the version) and to avoid too many acronym. It will help to find an answer.

Comment: Welcome, your question is hard to read, renforce what are you trying to do, what you have tryied before, and provide full details of your currents scenario especially OS.

Answer (score 1):

So the partition table is in place but you need to format the partition?

Take a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300415

Diskpart can be useful to inspect the drive and delete old partitions or create a new one.

**Be sure you select the correct drive! This will wipe your data**

An example could be like following (use search or `windows+R` and type `diskpart` to open the tool):

`list disk`

If disk 1 is your pen drive

`select disk 1`

Then clean the drive

`clean`

Then it should show up in your disk managment like you're used to again.
If not you probably have to work with the *delete partition* and the `override` parameter.

**Edit:**

If it's not visible in the explorer still - you probably need to assign a drive letter to the partition you created again.
Please take a look at the Microsoft documentation here (applies to Windows 7/8) http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter